# name 'FillMissing' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

When I run following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/marketingrar/marketing.csv')
df.head()
dep_var = 'Revenue'
cat_names = ['Day_Name','Promo']
cont_names = ['Date','Week','Month','Month_ID','Year','Visitors','Marketing Spend']
procs = [FillMissing, Categorify, Normalize]
```

I got this error bellow:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 procs = [FillMissing, Categorify, Normalize]
>
> NameError: name 'FillMissing' is not defined

P.S. I'm using Kaggle notebook. Why this error occurs and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`from fastai.tabular.all import *`
is the only working solution for me

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you are trying to initiate a list named procs with the 3 references to FillMissing, Categorify and Normalise, but you never created those references before.
Did you maybe want to create a list of 3 strings? Then you forgot the '', compare the other lists like cat_names or cont_names

Maybe it could also help to include

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.tabular import *
```

Comment: No bro, this should be working, but from some reason it won't. FillMissing, Categorify ad Normalize exist inside fast.ai library.

Comment: Did you make an import with * ? Cause otherwise you would have to write fastai.FillMissing and so on

Comment: OMG thank you so much, I forget to import 'tabular' modul, ohhhh! It's to late, I'm off to sleep. Thanks!!!

Comment: If the above doesn't work try `from fastai.tabular.all import *`

Comment: this from fastai.tabular.all import * work for me, thanks joanfbsm